# Any knows the method addinfocallback() in JuMP@0.18 now is replaced by what?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I found following method `addinfocallback()` in the document of JuMP beta0.18, but couldn't find any in the latest beta's document.
Did anyone know any?

```
solutionvalues = Vector{Float64}[]

# build model ``m`` up here

function infocallback(cb)
    push!(solutionvalues, JuMP.getvalue(x))
end
addinfocallback(m, infocallback, when = :MIPSol)

solve(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent. Here are the docs: https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/manual/callbacks/

If you want to find multiple MIP solutions, use:
https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/manual/solutions/#Multiple-solutions